# modify data/data/packagename/database without root permission in android programatically

Tags: android

My phone has not root permission. I want to copy file from sdcard to data/data/packname/database folder programmatically. But file doesn't copy. copying operation doesn't give any exceptions. What's problem?

Comment: You can't access database folder of other application until you have rooted phone.

Comment: I could access the folder without root permission

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `database` folder only when create SQLite database. Any other access will be denied on non-rooted device. But you can copy db by your program: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957835/copy-sqlite-database-for-android-application).